# How to dynamically change filename in a vba for-loop?

Tags: excel, vba

The for-loop is:

```
numRow = Application.Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count - 1
For i = 1 To numRow
  Let wsIn.Range("BJ4") = i
  Application.Calculate
  Let strName = "Student_" & i & " Exam.pdf"
  Let strFile = strPath & strName
  wsOut.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
Next i
```

I want my file name (strName) to read the students name according to the name on the specific row the for loop is on.
The names are on column B and start on row 5.
In the loop (numRow) reads to the last row with value on column B.

Comment: What is `wsOut` (probable a sheet) and what why do you need it since you do not use at all? Please, edit your question and try better explaining **in words** what you try accomplishing. Please, also add a picture of your sheet to be processed.

Comment: Don't you want copying anything from `wsIn` to `wsOut` before exporting? You did not even `Set` the `wsOut` worksheet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access Excel cells directly, like this:

```
For i = 1 To numRow
  Let strName = Range("B" & i).Value
```

In case you want to go to another row, you can:

```
For i = 1 To numRow
  RowIndex = i + 5
  Let strName = Range("B" & RowIndex).Value
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I needed... Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Agree with comments - not the clearest question, but ..
I'd modify your code to iterate through the selected cells then xCel.Value will be the name you're looking for, as follows

```
Dim R1 as Range, xCel as range, i as long

Set R1 = Application.Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
for each xCel in R1.Cells
   i = i+1
   Let wsIn.Range("BJ4") = i
   Application.Calculate
   Let strName = "Student_" & xCel.Value & " Exam.pdf"
   Let strFile = strPath & strName
   wsOut.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
Next xCel
```